# Proof Verification - divisibility through induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility, solution-verification

I'm studying for a final and was wondering if this proof is correct. I've seen several variants but they all seem less logical, so I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

The proof is essentially:
Prove, using induction that $5 | 11^{n} - 6$, for all positive integers n

Here is my proof:
Base case, n = 1

$11^1 - 6 = 5$ which is divisible by 5.

Inductive hypothesis:: Assume the proposition is true for some $k \in Z^{+}$, or 5|$11^k - 6$

Inductive step: Prove, using the assumption made in the previous step that $5 | 11^{k+1} - 6$
From our inductive hypothesis we know that there exists some positive integer a such that 5a = $11^{k} - 6$

$5 | 11^{k+1} - 6 $

$11^{k+1} - 6 $ = $11^k * 11^1 - 6$
but, we know that 5a = $11^k - 6$, so substituting, we get:
$11*5a = 55a$, which is a factor of 5.

Thus, the proposition holds.

Comment: Why do you say $5|11^{k+1} - 6\cdot 11^{k+1} - 6$? And why do you say $11^{k+1} - 6\cdot 11^{k+1} - 6 = 11^k*11^k - 6$?  And what does that have to do with $11*5a = 55a$?  Which is a *multiple* of $5$; not a factor of $5$.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, I've edited my solution.

Comment: also, if something is a multiple of 5, then it is a factor of 5, I thought

Comment: Not following your substitution step. Seems to me easiest approach is to use the fact that $11^k$ always ends in 1 and therefore $11^k-6$ always ends in 5.

Comment: ah yes you're right, I have a mistake there, thanks!

Comment: A factor of $5$ is something that divides *into* $5$.  $1$ or $5$ are the only two factors of $5$.  If $5$ divides int $55a$ then $55a$ is a *multiple* of $5$ (and $5$ is a factor of *it*; it is not a factor of $5$).

Comment: "we know that 5a = 11k−6, so substituting, we get: 11∗5a=55a"  But $11*11^k -6 \ne 11(11^k -6)$.  And $55a = 11(11k-6) = 11^{k+1} - 66 \ne 11^{k+1} -6$.  You need to point out that $5a = 11^k -6$ so $11*5a = 11^{k+1}- 66$ so $11*5a +60= 11^{k+1}-6$ so $11^{k+1} - 6=5(11a + 12)$ which is a *MULTIPLE* of $5$ (and which *HAS* $5$ as a factor).

Comment: "Seems to me easiest approach is to use the fact that 11k always ends in 1"  But you have to prove that by induction first. "therefore 11k−6 always ends in 5"  How do you know that something that ends in $5$ is divisiblee by $5$.  You have to prove that by induction first as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier solution for the induction step may be that if $11^k-6=5m$ for some integer $m$,

i.e. $11^k=5m+6$

then $11^{k+1}=11(5m+6)=55m+66 = 5(11m+12)+6$

i.e. $11^{k+1}-6=5(11m+12)$

or in other words, if $11^k-6$ is a multiple of $5$ then $11^{k+1}-6$ is also a multiple of $5$